# Compare between 2 Excel files and give difference based on key column

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have 2 excel files (which can be coverted to CSV).

```
File 1:
Last Name  First Name  id(10 digit)  email   age  course
   abc       def       1234567890    axd     00    y2k
   bcd       efg       9012345875    bxe     11    k2z
   cnn       nbc       5678912345    cxn     00    z2k

File 2:
Group_ID    email     Person_ID  Name(Last,First)
1            axd      1234567890   def,abc
             cxn      5678912345   nbc,cnn
```

So I want to generate a file, which after comparing the file1[id] and file2[Person_ID] would give me the result (I could also compare between file1[email] and file2[email] as both the Person_ID and email should be unique in each row:

```
bcd       efg       9012345875    bxe     11    k2z
```

I haven't yet figured out what and how to use, but you could tell me what python df functions I could use.

Comment: Try this: `df1.ix[~df1['id'].isin(df2.Person_ID)]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you read file 1 and file 2 into pandas data frames df1 and df2,

df1.loc[df1['id'] != df2['Person_ID']]